# How to adjust UITableview margins from left and right programmatically?

Tags: ios, ipad, ios6, ios7

i have a tableview(no table view cell). My Application is running fine in iOS 6 but when i am running it in iOS7 Tableview margin is conflicting.When i am setting up frame via Code its margin is only adjusting from left and bottom. i am using following code

```
if([[[UIDevice currentDevice]systemVersion]floatValue]>=7){
CGRect newSize = CGRectMake(0,0,730,925);
newSize.origin.y = 0;
newSize.size.width = 728.0;
newSize.size.height = 925.0;
self.myTable.frame = newSize;
}
```

Please suggest me something how can i resolve it
?
Here are images for ios 6 & ios 7 (Its a group table view ) i havent changed any margin for ios 7 its same as in ios6 ,and if i am doing any changes in ios 7 regarding margin its affecting in ios 6 layout too.. 
 [image: ios 6 Preview]
 [image: ios 7 Preview]

Comment: So what's the issue, get us a screenshot or a more clear description of your problem??

Comment: you have to set `newSize.origin.y = somevalue;` so that it would reflect the change from both the side.

Comment: @Augustine i have uploaded snaps please have a look.

Comment: @MayurShrivas i have tried this but its setting up margin only for left side.

Answer (score 0):

**Add autoresize property**

**//ensure autosizing enabled**

```
self.view.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
myTable = [[myTable alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
[myTable setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];
[self.view addSubview:myTable];
```

Comment: but how to set margin for both left & Right at once ?